# marginRight not working in RelativeLayout

Tags: android-studio

I have the following code but somehow the button I have on the right is stuck to the edge instead of having a margin of 41dp to the left of imageView. Is there anyway I can have have a working marginRight of 41dp (similar to the left button I have)

Have been stuck at this simple problem for a ridiculous amount of time, help is appreciated!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="338dp"
            android:layout_height="338dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/formal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dislike"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_down_white" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/like"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_thumbs_up_white" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="94dp"
            android:text="WEAR THIS" />



    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="338dp"
                android:layout_height="338dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="WEAR THIS"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is

[image: The Result]